# Documentation HTML section

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

I noticed there's currently a bit of a confusion in the documentation's HTML section. The current topics mostly speak about multiple tags (like the "Tables" or "Lists" topics), but some topics and proposals about single elements (like "Label" or "Meta") started appearing.

We obviously can't have a topic about every single element separately, so they should be a way to couple multiple elements together.

How should it be done?

Comment: I think it's too early to really be concerned about this. We should just let the information accumulate and see what kinds of things get presented and how. Repetitive information can later be removed, and examples can later be moved between topics if they should be merged together. We definitely shouldn't expect it to be perfect *as we create it*. There's going to be a lot of redoing things before we get to the point where we reach a good organizational scheme for this. Try not to write the final product before you've actually made an outline.